# NSData узнать количество элементов

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Для NSArray есть count, для NSData такого не нашел
Нужно посчитать количество элементов, как это можно сделать грамотно?

```
NSData *receivedData = [@"{\n"
                        "\"Name\": \"Все\",\n"
                        "\"Market\":\n" "[{\n"
                            "\"ID\": \"1\",\n"
                            "\"Name\": \"Товар 1\",\n"
                            "},\n"
                            "{\n"
                            "\"ID\": \"2\",\n"
                            "\"Name\": \"Товар 2\",\n"
                            "}]\n"
                        "}" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для `NSData` нельзя узнать `count`, по всей видимости в `NSData` у Вас `JSON`. Если так, то Вы можете конвертировать `NSData` в `NSDictionary`:

```
NSError *errorJson=nil;
NSDictionary* responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: receivedData options:kNilOptions error:&errorJson];
```

И тогда Вы можете использовать `count` для `NSDictionary`:

```
[responseDict count];
```